# JavaScript date from string?

Tags: javascript

Novice question. I've got a string in the following format:

```
var dateStr = '2012-4-14';
```

I want to make it into a JavaScript Date object. The following creates a Date object in Chrome, but is NaN in IE8:

```
var myDate = new Date(dateStr);
```

What should I be doing differently - should I split the string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try splitting your date string into year, month, day and instantiating your date differently.

```
var rawDate = '2012-4-14'.split('-');

var myDate = new Date(rawDate[0], rawDate[1]-1, rawDate[2]);
```

Note that this will only work if you can guarantee that your date string will be of the same format each time.

Comment: Don't forget that months are 0 based in JavaScript, so you should subtract `1` from the month if April is desired..

Comment: @amnotiam I can't believe I missed that! Considering that this bit me in the *** just the other day.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) in javascript, it recognizes various date formats, see the MDN page for details. For ISO 8601 dates (yours seem to be this one) you can use [this library](https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601/tree/lax).

This answer also could prove itself useful: [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

Answer (score 0):

Change `var dateStr = '2012-4-14';` to `var dateStr = '2012/4/14';`